# How to get exact 8 digit from string using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

My requirement is to get exact 8 digit from giver string.

let me give you some example.

1. **000012345678000** : This is not allowed because it has more than 8 digit. So"12345678" should not be extracted
2. **0000 12345678 000** : This is allowed because 8 digit is separate.
3. **0000 12345678. ABCKSAKU** : This is allowed.
4. **0000.12345678.ABCKSAKU** : This is allowed.
5. **0000/12345678/ABCKSAKU** : This is allowed.

In short separate 8 digit is allowed. Is should not be within any number.

i have tried.

**\s{1,}\d{8}\s{1,}** but is only allows 8 digit with blank space at both side.

Can you please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: 0 isn't a digit in your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\s{1,}\d{8}\s{1,}` pattern indeed matches only in between whitespaces as `\s{1,}` (equal to `\s+`) matches 1 or more whitespace chars.

You may use lookarounds to match a sequence of digits that are not enclosed with other digits:

```
(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%5Cd%7B8%7D%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=000012345678000%20%3A%20This%20is%20not%20allowed%20%0D%0A0000%2012345678%20000%20%3A%20This%20is%20allowed%20because%208%20digit%20is%20separate.%0D%0A0000%2012345678.%20ABCKSAKU%20%3A%20This%20is%20allowed.%0D%0A0000.12345678.ABCKSAKU%20%3A%20This%20is%20allowed.%0D%0A0000%2F12345678%2FABCKSAKU%20%3A%20This%20is%20allowed.)

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\d)` -  a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the left of the current position
- `\d{8}` - 8 digits
- `(?!\d)`-  a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current position.

In C#, use the following code to get all the matches:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Note that `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option will make `\d` only match ASCII digits.

**Word boundary note**: You may consider word boundaries `\b` instead of the lookarounds, but there is a catch. If you need to extract 8 digits from `_12345678_` string, you cannot use a `\b\d{8}\b` pattern. If you want this match to fail, you may use `\b\d{8}\b`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use word boundary (`\b`) as follows:

```
\b\d{8}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the regex you want :

```
.*([. \/])+([1-9]{8})([. \/])+.*
```

before the numbers should be one or more space and backslash and dot after that too and number shouldn't have zero and after and before spaces and dots and backslash anything can be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk4BE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is enough to check whether it is a last one not-digit character on left and right and make it optional as "12345678" should mean that there no digits around too:

`(\D)?\d{8}(\D)?`